# Upgrade to a newer version using WIX Installer doesn't copy the new files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an already installed MSI package from V1 to V2.
The MSI package is part of a bundle (we have 10 different MSI packages in the bundle, but only this one is causing upgrade issues).

The problem I have is that after upgrade the new version appears correct in Control Panel but when I go to the disk the new files are not copied and I'm left with the old files on the disk (V1 files).
If I do a Repair from Control Panel the new files get copied with the correct version.

I am using WixSharp version 1.4.4.1.

Does anyone know why the upgrade is not done properly?

An example of how the Bundle.wxs looks like can be found below:

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
      xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
      xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
      xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
     <Bundle Name="Test.Installer"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.Test_Package_msi)"
          Manufacturer="Test"
          UpgradeCode="bdbd5b31-e749-455d-9fea-cd81f3297ca1"    >

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id ="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
      <PayloadGroupRef Id ="InstallerPayload" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id ="NetFx472Redist" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id ="InstallerPackages" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
        <?define NetFx472MinVersion = 4703062 ?>
        <?define NetFx472EulaLink = https://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html ?>
        <?define NetFx472RedistLink = https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863265 ?>

     <Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx472Redist" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="$(var.NetFx472EulaLink)" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="NetFx472RedistCondition" Value="Netfx4FullVersion &gt;= $(var.NetFx472MinVersion)" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="NetFx472RedistPackageDirectory" Value="Redist\NETFX472\" Overridable="yes" />

       <util:RegistrySearch
       Root="HKLM"
       Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
       Value="Version"
       Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />

    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx472Redist">
      <ExePackage
          DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2"
          InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx472FullLog].html&quot;"
          RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx472FullLog].html&quot;"
          UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx472FullLog].html&quot;"
          PerMachine="yes"
          DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx472RedistCondition)"
          InstallCondition="NOT !(wix.NetFx472RedistCondition)"
          DownloadUrl="$(var.NetFx472RedistLink)"
          Id="NetFx472Redist"
          Vital="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Protocol="netfx4"
          Compressed="yes"
          SourceFile="..\Redist\NETFX472\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
          Name="!(wix.NetFx472RedistPackageDirectory)NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
        >
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <PayloadGroup Id ="InstallerPayload">
      <Payload SourceFile = "$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile = "$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile = "$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile = "$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile = "$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\log4net.dll"/>
  </PayloadGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id ="InstallerPackages">
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Libraries\MSI\Package1.msi" ForcePerMachine="yes"
          Id="Package1_msi" DisplayName="Package 1" Visible="yes" Cache="yes" DisplayInternalUI="no" Description="23A29233-37FD-4079-92AF-8337998DF4D3">
      </MsiPackage>
    <!-- 10 other packages -->
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The MSI project is created using the following lines:

```
   var project = new ManagedProject();
    project.Name = "Test";
    project.Description = "Test Package";
    project.GUID = Guid.Parse("{94682162-F133-40A3-92BB-0AF08142474C}");
    project.ProductId = Guid.Parse("{94682162-F133-40A3-92BB-0AF08142474C}");
    project.Dirs = GetDirectoriesAndFilesToInstall();
    project.Version = GetInstallerVersion();
    project.BannerImage = "Banner.bmp";

    project.Actions = new WixSharp.Action[]
    {
        new ElevatedManagedAction(CustomActions.UninstallService, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallInitialize, Condition.Always),
        new ElevatedManagedAction(CustomActions.InstallService, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallExecute, Condition.Always),
    };

    project.BuildMsi(msiPath);
```

Comment: Have you tried to add "new Property("REINSTALLMODE", "amus")" for force files reinstall?

Comment: Yes, tried that but didn't do anything. The old version of the files stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the upgrade only works if you add files during the upgrade, not if you remove files.

I compared the old installation with the new one and 6 files were missing from the new one. Because of that the upgrade didn't update any files at all.

The article that inspired me can be found here:
[MSI Installer Rules](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2011/06/17/145898.aspx)

I realized that I broke Rule 2: Only add, never remove resources from a component

This is somehow weird, what if I want to remove files during an upgrade? What solutions do I have?

UPDATE: I found out that the MajorUpgrade can be forced in code like below:

```
var project = new ManagedProject
        {
            Name = "Your name",
            Description = "Your description",
            GUID = Guid.Parse("{94682162-F133-40A3-92BB-0AF08142474C}"),
            MajorUpgrade = new MajorUpgrade
            {
                DowngradeErrorMessage = $"A later version of {projectName} is already installed. Setup will now exit."
            },
            Actions = new WixSharp.Action[]
            {
                new ElevatedManagedAction(CustomActions.UninstallService, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallInitialize, Condition.Always),
                new ElevatedManagedAction(CustomActions.InstallService, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallExecute, Condition.Always),
            }
        };
```

and you don't need to change the major part in the assembly version.
For instance, if the existing installer had version 1.1.0.0 installed, then you can force a Major Upgrade in code but change the version to 1.2.0.0 instead of changing to 2.0.0.0.

Also, in the installer bundle project I had to add this property: EnableFeatureSelection="yes" for each of the MSIPackage element. This property enables you to catch the event named: DetectRelatedMsiPackage. This will help you to differentiate between versions and identify which package is installed or not and also which one can be upgraded.

Comment: That is the behavior for a minor upgrade. I recommend 99% of  MSI developers to instead be using Major Upgrades. Is that WiXCharp your using? Interesting concept but not interested in it as it hides the underlying WiX too much.  I have an open source tool you might find useful.  https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Comment: PS- If staying with Minor upgrades this property MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msienforceupgradecomponentrules) will help you avoid these issues.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherPainter, I tried setting the Property and also the Policy but I got an error during upgrade saying: "An error occurred with the installation of the package. A restart is needed in order to proceed with installation." The files remain with the V1 file version and never get incremented to V2 file version.